# Usando UIInterfaceOrientation para mudar de tela

Tags: ios, objective-c, gui

Preciso saber como faço para mudar a tela do iPhone quando ela é girada (De Portrait para Landscape).

Por exemplo, quando estiver em modo Portrait ele apresente a Tela A, quando estiver em Left Landscape ele apresente a tela B e quando virado para Right Landscape seja apresentado a tela C.

Ou seja, que ele dispare o método `presentViewController:animated:completion:` quando ocorrer a mudança de orientação da tela, ou algum outro método que seja específico para este comportamento.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer isso através do método:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Antes da orientação da interface ser mudada, verificas qual a orientação para qual a aplicação irá e fazes o present do ViewController correspondente.

Será algo deste género:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

        // Do Something

    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        // Do Something    

    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Vou testar e ja trago a resposta!!

Comment: Sua resposta foi muito útil... mas agora o rumo é outro... Me pediram essa solução em Swift :P